# iOS UIImageView not updating image when loaded

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an app using a `UINavigationController`. In one view I have a series of buttons that passes an ID to another view. This new view then displays a relevant image from the database depending on what button was selected in the previous view. However, it works great for the first time, but if I click the 'Back' button on the Navigation and return to the button list view and try clicking on another button it still displays the what ever the previous image was. It seems like its cacheing or something?

I hope that it makes sense, and any help very much appreciated.

As requested, some code to go with it:

ProductView.m

```
//Background Image
               UIImage *itemBgImage = [UIImage imageNamed: [row stringForColumn:@"bg_image_iphone"]];
            UIImageView *itemBgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
            itemBgImageView.image = itemBgImage;

itemBgImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width,  self.view.bounds.size.height);

[self.view addSubview:itemBgImageView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:itemBgImageView];

itemBgImage = nil;
[itemBgImage release];

itemBgImageView = nil;
[itemBgImageView release];
```

Comment: Do you have some code to go with that problem?

Comment: Updated with code, the database is 100% getting the correct information.

Comment: If you're pushing the same instance of `ProductView` every time, then it's adding a new UIImageView* every time and not removing it after, try save itemBgImageView and just change the `itemBgImageView.image` property if it's already created...

Comment: I have tried your sugesstion jjv360 but still getting the same issue :( I have updated my OP with the newer code.

Comment: Where did you implement or add the ProductView ? If you did it in viewDidLoad keep in mind, that this will be only called once (the first time) due to your navigation controller. After the first opening only viewDid/WillAppear will get called again (except there was a memory warning and the view controller got released for sure).
So it does not only depend on your view code, but on the code in your view controller. Also check if the product view gets "relayouted" and not added more than once

Comment: Thanks Alexander, the code was in my viewWillAppear methods already. 

I think that I have fixed it now, seems that when I was adding the subview, then assigning to the back, however, when I send the view to the back, then add it, it seems to work as it should.

Comment: @TheRabbitFactory Sending the subview to the back before even adding it makes no sense. You might as well get rid of the line of code where you send your view to the back cause it does nothing. Also you are leaking itemBgImageView cause you are setting it to nil before sending it a release message. You don't need to release itemBgImage though as it is an autoreleased object. I suggest you grab an iOS development book and study because learning by attempts doesn't always work and takes longer than reading a book.